# groupby max without dropping columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Hi I am having the following hypothetical df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'sp' : ['MM1', 'MM1', 'MM1', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM2', 'MM4', 'MM4','MM4'],
'mt' : ['S1', 'S1', 'S3', 'S3', 'S4', 'S4', 'S2', 'S2', 'S2'],
'val' : ['a', 'n', 'cb', 'mk', 'bg', 'dgb', 'rd', 'cb', 'uyi'],
'count' : [3,2,5,8,10,1,2,2,7]
})
top =df.groupby(['sp','mt']).agg({'count':'max'})
top
```

I do what to group by sp and mt without dropping the val column, how can I do this? The idea is to find the value of val where count is max

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple values of val. Your request is only valid when you say find the value of val where count 'reaches' max

Comment: thanks Aaj for your comments, that is exactly what I am trying to achieved here, any hints?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question.  There are *many* similar operations when it comes to groupby, count, max, etc.

Comment: Sort values by 'count' then drop duplicates on sp and mt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.idxmax` as an index with `.loc`

```
idx = df.groupby(['sp', 'mt'])['count'].idxmax()
df.loc[idx.values, :]

    sp  mt  val  count
2  MM1  S3   cb      5
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
8  MM4  S2  uyi      7
```

Answer (score 0):

Option#1 - extension to your effort using `groupby`

```
df['count1'] = df.groupby(['sp','mt'])['count'].transform('max')
df = df[df['count'] == df['count1']].drop('count1',axis=1)
```

Option#2 using `sort` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df = df.sort_values('count',ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['sp','mt']).sort_index()
```

Both prints:

```
    sp  mt  val  count
0  MM1  S1    a      3
2  MM1  S3   cb      5
3  MM2  S3   mk      8
4  MM2  S4   bg     10
8  MM4  S2  uyi      7
```